# How can I upgrade Docker on a Mac?

Tags: macos, docker

I tried just 'docker-machine upgrade' and that did some work but I don't seem to have the latest CLI.

If I do 'docker version' I get:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.8.2
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   0a8c2e3
 Built:        Thu Sep 10 19:10:10 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        2016-06-01T21:20:08.558909126+00:00
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

I understand there are some new commands I'm not seeing so I suspect I don't have the latest software.

Comment: You can dowload toolbox and reinstall only the docker client. If you also upgrade using brew

Comment: Hello @Greg, when you execute the `docker-machine upgrade default` you are upgrading your virtual machine and not your docker client. They are different things!

Comment: If you've installed docker with brew, you might have to specify full path to upgrade. So running this command: brew upgrade homebrew/cask/docker

Answer (score 89):

Surprisingly, this GUI button helped me.

[image]

Comment: A picture worth a thousand words :)

Comment: I hung my head in shame after this :).

Answer (score 33):

Since you are on mac, you should install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and from there you can install and upgrade docker with the command `brew install docker` and `brew upgrade`. Homebrew is a package manager for mac that makes installation of such applications easy.

Comment: He need a solution for his problem and not a new installer

Comment: After installing docker with homebrew, it will help you getting rid of the old installation:

`Could not symlink bin/docker`
`Target /usr/local/bin/docker already exists. You may want to remove it:`
`rm /usr/local/bin/docker`
`To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:`
`brew link --overwrite docker`
`To list all files that would be deleted:`
`brew link --overwrite --dry-run docker`

Comment: @Leszek is correct - I hadn't originally used homebrew to install the Docker CLI, but I was able to do so by running `brew install docker` then `rm '/usr/local/bin/docker'` then `brew link docker`. After that it's easy to update the version at any time by running `brew upgrade docker` or just `brew upgrade` to update all packages managed by homebrew.

Comment: If you've used formulae (i.e. 'brew install docker') then use 'brew upgrade docker'. If you've installed docker as a desktop app using cask (i.e. 'brew install --cask docker') then use 'brew upgrade --cask docker')

Answer (score 6):

For **homebrew** users: I needed to overwrite the last version of docker by using:

```
brew link --overwrite docker
```

Check with

```
docker --version
```

Answer (score 5):

if it requires update, it will show that in the menu when it's running.
You will see "Download & Update".
Once download finishes, you will see something like this (notice the before last option) :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just try this way:

```
$ mkdir ~/docker
$ curl -Lo  ~/docker/docker-1.13.0-dev https://master.dockerproject.org/darwin/amd64/docker-1.13.0-dev
$ sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker
$ sudo ln -s ~/docker/docker-1.13.0-dev /usr/local/bin/docker
```

you can find all current master branch in [this link](https://master.dockerproject.org/linux/amd64/)

Comment: They only make linux and windows binaries there now though.

Answer (score -3):

This was super annoying... turns out to be a button.

docker-compose v2 enable.
[image]