# How to upgrade Docker on Mac from boot2docker version?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645134/how-can-i-upgrade-docker-on-a-mac) asks prior to the 17.0.3 Docker-style versions.

My specific question is how (on a Mac) does one upgrade from a boot2docker version (mine is 1.12.3) to 17.0.3 or later?  Please list all commands required.  [The Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/upgrade/) seems to indicate using docker-machine, but this did not alter the version at all for me, though it did run successfully.